# How do I add check boxes to my columns in my list view?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, custom-list, column

In the image below I would like the columns that say yes to be check boxes instead of text. The columns are set up as Yes/No column type. Is this possible?

[image: img.jpg]

Comment: You want them displayed as Checkboxes; or also acting as Checkbox and thus not a View or Displayform but Editform functionality (in the View)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this

1. Using jQuery to dynamically change this on `document.ready` event
2. Recommended way - Using JSLinks

Option #2 you can use JavaScript to specify how a field should be rendered. For more check this article. http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: +1 for using client-side rendering script connected to the view through the JSLink property (option #2). (N.B. - JSLink is just a way to connect a Javascript file to a SharePoint object.  JSLink is not synonymous with client-side rendering, although it is certainly extremely useful for applying client-side rendering.)  [This article is a great resource on CSR.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

Comment: I'm going to give this shot and i will report back with my results. Thank you.